# Clarification on C pointers and memory addresses

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I am interested in line 6, 7 and 8 in the code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void go_south_east(int *lat, int *lon) {
  printf("Lat: %p, Long: %p\n", lat, lon);
  printf("Address of Lat: %p, Address of Long: %p\n", &lat, &lon);
  printf("Address of Lat: %p, Address of Long + 8 bytes?: %p\n", &lat, &lon+8);
  printf("Size of Lat: %lu, Size of Long: %lu\n", sizeof(lat), sizeof(lon));
  *lat -= 1;
  *lon += 1;
}

int main() {

  int latitude = 32;
  int longtitude = -64;
  go_south_east(&latitude, &longtitude);
  printf("Avast! Now at: [%i, %i]\n", latitude, longtitude);

  return 0;
}
```

The output I got was:

```
Address of Lat: 0x7fff5fbfe9e8, Address of Long: 0x7fff5fbfe9e0
Address of Lat: 0x7fff5fbfe9e8, Address of Long + 8 bytes?: 0x7fff5fbfea20 
Size of Lat: 8, Size of Long: 8
```

I understand that the size of the lat and long pointers are 8 bytes because they are long unsigned int. But why are they only 1 byte away from each other in the memory? Shouldn't they be 8 bytes away from each other since their size is 8 bytes? Please advice.

---

Thanks for all the helpful advice. I wished I could mark everyone's as answer but I can't. Really appreciate it.

Comment: 0x7fff5fbfe9e8 - 0x7fff5fbfe9e0 == 8

Comment: They are 8 bytes apart (e0 to e8).

Comment: This question is not really bad, but you could rewrite it better since I think a lot of beginners might have this same question. And to stop getting the downvotes by the pedantic ones.

Comment: But when I tried to do &lon+8, I do not get 0x7fff5fbfe9e8. Why?

Comment: @JohnLee That's because pointer arithmetic is not done in units of bytes, It's done in units of the type size.. `&long + 8` does not mean "address of long plus 8 bytes" it means "address of long plus 8 units of long". It advances the address by sizeof(long)*8 bytes.

Comment: No, `lat` and `long` are *not* `long unsigned int`; they're `int*`. Pointers are not integers.

Comment: @nos ahhhh I see. If I could ask one last question related to this. The address of lat and long are in hex. If I convert the least significant bit of both to base 2, it will be 1000 and 0000 right? Why is 1000 - 0000 = 8 bytes, isn't it 8 bits ?

Comment: @KeithThompson Oh ya you are right. They are indeed int pointers

Comment: @KeithThompson Correct me if I am wrong. The size of pointers depends on if your OS is 32bits (4 bytes) and 64bits (8 bytes) ?

Comment: Addressess are in bytes, not bits.

Comment: @JohnLee No, memory addresses on an x86 machine (and most other common processors) are in units of 8 bits, i.e. a byte in common speak.

Comment: @JohnLee, no, the size of pointers depend on your implementation.

Comment: @JohnLee: The size of pointers (which is *usually* the same for all pointer types, but needn't be) is determined by the compiler. Compiler authors almost always choose pointer sizes based on the characteristics of the underlying system.

Comment: @nos: I think you misunderstood. The size of a pointer object is typically 32 or 64 bits (4 or 8 bytes). The granularity of the memory address a pointer points to is, in one sense, 1 byte. On the other hand, the granularity of a C pointer is the size of the object it points to; incrementing an `int*` pointer value by 1 causes it to point to the next `int` object in memory.

Comment: @KeithThompson It seems JohnLee asked another question in the mean time - as I was answering why the difference of 8 between the 2 addresses he printed out means bytes, not bits. (And to not add too much confusion I left out the part where a byte in C is not necessarily 8 bits, though)

Comment: @nos if I could asked a more granular question. For what i know now, memory address from 0x0 to 0x1 is a difference of 8 bits, how should I model this in my head? One way I tried but failed is to convert the hex address to binary, so it becomes 0000 to 0001. It's hard to imagine that 0000 to 0001 is a difference of 8 bits. Is there some subtraction operation going on or am I just confused?

Comment: @John Lee There's really nothing going on. A memory address is an index to a block of memory that's 8 bits wide. The next memory address is the index to the next block of memory, 8 bits wide. So there's 8 bits inbetween each address. Memory is not built so you can address individual bits, you can only address individual bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a wild mix up of completely different things and unexplainable assertions in your question.

Firstly, I don't see an `long unsigned int` pointers in your code. All pointers in your code have `int *` type. Where did `long unsigned int` come from?

Secondly, `lat` and `lon` are data pointers. Typically, in a non-exotic C implementation all data pointers have the same size. It doesn't matter what they point to. On your platform data pointers have 8-byte size. That means that pointers to `char` and well as pointers to `double` as well as pointers to `unsigned long int` will have the same 8-byte size.

Thirdly, where did you get the idea that they are 1 byte away in memory? The very first line in your output clearly shows that they are located at `0x7fff5fbfe9e8` and `0x7fff5fbfe9e0` addresses. These addresses are exactly 8 bytes away: `0x7fff5fbfe9e8` minus `0x7fff5fbfe9e0` equals 8. So, where did your "1 byte away" come from?

Fourthly, your code seems to suggest that `&lon+8` changes the address by "8 bytes". This is incorrect. Adding 1 to a data pointer `T*` shifts it by `sizeof(T)` bytes, which means that `&lon+8` actually changes the address by 8*8=64 bytes, which is exactly what you observe in your output: `0x7fff5fbfea20` minus `0x7fff5fbfe9e0` equals 64.

Basically, the questions you ask are directly contradicting what you observe in your output. That's kinda makes it virtually impossible to answer. It is like showing people a red handkerchief and asking why it is green.

Comment: That is exactly why I ask this question. I know I am wrong, it's just that, I can't seem to convince my brain to think that it's red because of my lack of knowledge. In short, I couldn't model how the computer memory worked in my mind, which made me confused.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between those two addresses is exactly 8, have a look again.

Answer (score 0):

They are eight bytes away from one another. PCs are *byte* addressable, not bit addressable.

That is to say that the numbered memory units are *bytes*.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer arithmetic actually adds the size of the data type to the address. To clarify:

```
int* i = 0;
i++;
printf("%p\n", i); // Prints 0x4, not 0x1
```

So

```
printf("Address of Lat: %p, Address of Long + 8 bytes?: %p\n", &lat, &lon+8);
```

Actually prints the address of lon + 8 * sizeof(&lon) bytes